# OData queries and types other than IQueryable in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am building an ASP.NET Web API application that returns an Atom or an RSS feed. To do this, it builds a `System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed` and a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` is responsible for handling the HTTP Accept Header, converting the `SyndicationFeed` to either an `Atom10FeedFormatter` or an `Rss20FeedFormatter`, and streaming the result to the response stream. So far, so good.

My controller looks something like this:

```
    public class FeedController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            FeedRepository feedRepository = new FeedRepository();
            HttpResponseMessage<SyndicationFeed> successResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage<SyndicationFeed>(feedRepository.GetSyndicationFeed());
            return successResponseMessage;
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is make use of the built-in OData querying to filter my feed, but changing the return type of the `Get()` method to `IQueryable<SyndicationFeed>` obviously will not work since a `SyndicationFeed` does not implement `IQueryable`.

Is there a way to use the built in OData querying on the `IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>` property on the `SyndicationFeed`?

Answer (score 3):

This question is no longer relevant, since Microsoft remove the rudimentary support for OData querying that was in the Beta build of Web API.

A future version will include more complete OData support. There is an early build of this available via CodePlex and NuGet and there are more details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: Did u find any solution for ur question?? I am facing a similar problem....plz check my question and let me know if u can help in any way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451649/how-to-apply-paging-specifically-to-a-list-which-is-part-of-a-json-using-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

The System.Linq namespace provides an extension method named [AsQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx)  to the `IEnumerable` interface. Your code would look along the lines of this:

```
public class FeedController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable<SyndicationFeed> Get()
    {
        FeedRepository feedRepository = new FeedRepository();

        //TODO: Make sure your property handles empty/null results:
        return feedRepository.GetSyndicationFeed()
                   .YourEnumerableProperty.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that will not work because the return type is wrong. In your example, it is expecting an IQueryable<SyndicationFeed> but you would be returning an IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>. The SyndicationFeed does not implement IQueryable but I can't discard it because it is the envelope for my RSS or Atom feed. The question is, how do I get the OData query to filter the IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> while still keeping the SyndicationFeed as my return type?

Comment: `return syndicationItems.AsQueryable();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return IQuerable from controller when working with OData.
Check "Invoking Query Options Directly" section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

For your case it will looks like:

```
public SyndicationFeed Get(ODataQueryOptions<SyndicationItem> opts)
{
    var settings = new ODataValidationSettings();

    opts.Validate(settings);

    SyndicationFeed result = feedRepository.GetSyndicationFeed();

    result.Items = opts.ApplyTo(result.Items.AsQuerable()).ToArray();

    return result;
}
```